# Sum of Components of k-dimensional Inverse Hypergeometric Random Variable is... Inverse Hypergeometric?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have come around the following statement regarding a multivariate inverse (negative) hypergeometric distribution in Section 11 of >>Guenther, William C. "The inverse hypergeometric‐a useful model." Statistica Neerlandica 29, no. 4 (1975): 129-144., https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9574.1975.tb00257.x<<

> \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}&[X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,\dots,X_k=x_k,]=p^*(N,n,d_1,\dots,d_k,x_1,\dots,x_k)\\&=
> \frac{\begin{pmatrix}x_1-1\\d_1-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_2-1\\d_2-1\end{pmatrix}\dots\begin{pmatrix}x_k-1\\d_k-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}N-\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\\n-\sum_{i=1}^kd_i\end{pmatrix}}
> {\begin{pmatrix}N\\n\end{pmatrix}}\\&x_i\geq d_i,\quad i= 1,2,\dots,k\quad\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\leq N-n+\sum_{i=1}^kd_i\end{align*}
> We will call $(X_1, X_2, . . ., X_k)$ a k-dimensional inverse hypergeometric random variable. [$\dots$] It is easy to verify that a multivariate inverse hypergeometric probability function defined by (11.2) has the property that all marginals and conditionals are also multivariate (or one variable) inverse hypergeometric. $\color{blue}{\text{In addition } X_1 + X_2, X_1 + X_2 + X_3, \text{or a sum of any number of } X\text{'s}}$ $\color{blue}{\text{has an inverse hypergeometric distribution.}}$
> These are properties enjoyed by the multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

My interest lies with the blue colored text. It is not immediately obvious to me, why such a statement would be true in general, and I might be misunderstanding something crucial here. Suppose, for instance, that all $X_i$'s are independent, then the distribution of their sum would be given by the convolution of their marginal (inverse hypergeometric) distributions. How does one conclude that this pmf is again inverse hypergeometric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $X_i$'s are not independent, since they represent the counts for each category.

The text says that each $X_i$ (inside a multivariate inverse hypergeometric random vector) individually has a (univariate) inverse hypergeometric distribution. The part in blue says that if you merge say categories 1 and 2, then the marginal count $X_1 + X_2$ for those merged categories will again be (univariate) inverse hypergeometric. The same is true if you merge 3 categories, etc.